# how to link Glib in win7

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, glib

i'm compiling lightspark on windows7.
However,when it link glib,there're many errors,such as:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   Glib::Mutex::unlock(void)" (?unlock@Mutex@Glib@@QAEXXZ)   "
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   Glib::Cond::Cond(void)" (??0Cond@Glib@@QAE@XZ)        "
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   Glib::Cond::~Cond(void)   "

And I use `dumbbin` tool get something like this:

> ?unlock@Mutex@Glib@@QEAAXXZ (public: void __cdecl
>   Glib::Mutex::unlock(void))
>
> ??0Cond@Glib@@QEAA@XZ (public: __cdecl Glib::Cond::Cond(void))
>
> ??1Cond@Glib@@QEAA@XZ (public: __cdecl Glib::Cond::~Cond(void))

what's the reason about this problem?Any idea appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Those symbols aren't part of glib, they're part of glibmm (C++ bindings for glib).  If you're only trying to link to glib and not glibmm, it's a good bet that that is your problem.

Comment: I'm actually linking glibmm,and the `dumpbin` tool get symbols from glibmm too